# How to restore database with impdp

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I have Oracle 12c database and I execute expdp command to create dump file. Later I want to be able to restore database using this dump file, **on the same location** as where the dump was created from. I don't want to stop database, which is required to drop schema (or execute any 'shutdown immediate', which is required for doing the same with flashbacks).

If I execute impdp with remap_schema=myschema:myschema, I get many errors. When I try it with table_exists_action=replace, I also get errors (ORA numbers: 31684, 39111, 39083, 31085, 39325, 31061, 06512, 29329).

How can I restore database in the same location? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't specify whether this was a schema level export or database level export.  But in either case, can't this be achieved by dropping the user(s) required, and then running impdp in the normal way.

Comment: When I do that, I receive less errors, but they are still present: ORA-20000, ORA-39082.

Comment: What I've tried was exporting, dropping several users, then importing, then I had these ORA-20000 and ORA-39082

Comment: Solution found: I haven't included correct list of schemas